# Does an earthquake affect GPS?

Tags: gps

There are [news](http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/asiapcf/03/12/japan.earthquake.tsunami.earth/index.html) [reports](http://www.voanews.com/english/news/asia/Japans-Earthquake-Alters-Coast-Line-Changes-Earths-Axis-117857349.html) saying that the [Sendai earthquake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Sendai_earthquake_and_tsunami) a couple days ago has shifted the earth on its axis and moved the island 8 feet.

Last year, there were [similar reports](http://www.scientificamerican.com/blog/post.cfm?id=how-the-earthquake-in-chile-changed-2010-03-02) with the earthquake in Chile.

Does this affect GPS devices at all?  Is an inaccuracy introduced?  How does GPS still work if the earth has shifted on its axis?

Comment: The GPS satellites are recalibrated (ephemeris data update) from ground-based stations every couple hours. If the whole earth shifted uniformly, would GPS automatically get updated to the new position within a few hours?

Comment: @freiheit The whole earth indeed is constantly "shifting uniformly" as it rotates about its axis.  In order to change that measurably, you would need to bring a truly massive gravitational body close to the earth for some time.  Remember, too, Newton's laws: the action of the earthquake generated a reaction within the earth's crust; the net motion was *zero*.

Comment: @whuber: yes, I'm aware of the uniform shifts of the surface due to rotation, as well as fairly uniform shifts due to wobbling of that axis on several periods. The news reports I saw were indicating some kind of new shift, both of Japan and the whole surface (smaller magnitude).

Comment: @freiheit There's an article on this in today's NY Times (http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/14/world/asia/14seismic.html?hp )  Buried at the end is this important statement: "Such changes are not unusual, and even without earthquakes, changes in ocean currents and atmospheric conditions usually have even greater effects [on mass shifts within the earth]. “The Earth is always wobbling, and the length of the day is always changing,” Dr. Gross said."

Comment: I think the technically correct answer is not posted so I'll give it a stab below, but as it involves general relativity I'll probably just cause confusion.

Answer (score 24):

Geologically speaking, the Earth's surface is always on the move due to [plate tectonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics). On average, your location is moving anywhere from 0 to 10 cm per year (relative to other positions on Earth).

You can see global changes in GPS positions throughout the world [here](http://sideshow.jpl.nasa.gov/mbh/series.html).

[image: Snapshot of the GPS positions]

Comment: I think this is a different effect than the one mentioned in the question. While there was a plate techtonic element to the movement of Japan due to the earthquake. The questioner is asking about the change to the world due to mass movement.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a great article from MSNBC on how the earthquake affects GPS data:

http://photoblog.nbcnews.com/_news/2011/03/12/6256280-how-the-quake-shifted-japan

> Everything that links GPS readings to
>   maps, ranging from driving directions
>   to property records, will have to be
>   changed as a result of the shift,
>   Hudnut [*Ken Hudnut, a geophysicist at the U.S. Geological Survey's Earthquake Hazards Program*] told me. "Their national
>   network for property boundary
>   definitions has been warped," he said
>   in an e-mail. "For ships, the nautical
>   charts will need revision due to
>   changed water depths, too (of about 3
>   feet). Much of the coastline dropped
>   by a few feet, too, we gather."

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but this is a change in what is at the location, it is not a flaw of GPS itself. The GPS still knows where you are, it just happens the channel moved 3 feet to the left.

Answer (score 5):

If the group moves to the left 8 feet and you move with it, your GPS will now say you are to the left 8 feet(if it had perfect accuracy).

If you tried to load a map of where you were the map would be off by 8 feet until they updated it. GPS is based on satellites, so to mess it up you would have to shift the world, but that has its own set of issues involving orbits.

Comment: Right, but the news reports are that the world has been moved.

Comment: @Marcin, which it has not. I mean the earth shifting in space by X meters while the rest of the universe is held still. The GPS system knows where you are as long as their is not a space level event. Your maps based on GPS need an update.

Comment: @Marcin, to be more clear, as long as the satellites do not move they can tell where you are in reference to the satellites, if a plate moves you will map incorrectly to where the road is, but they will know where you all.

Comment: maps will be changed, but your position on the globe does not.  GPS positioning is a function of time and space and does not rely on terrestrial maps.

Comment: @monkut, that is what I was attempting to explain. The fact that the earth shifted 8 feet will be correctly noted, but until they update your map they will have you offset from a real location by 8 feet. now will a plate every shift a whole area by 8 feet, no idea, i have no idea what goes on with an earthquake. But I know what gps is doing and my point is that it would still know your location, the maps would just be incorrect and have you 8 feet off the road you are on in this hypothetical case.

Answer (score 3):

I expect the change due to the earthquake to be on an order of magnitude as the [Chandler Wobble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_wobble) and I assume that GPS can handle that as it happens constantly.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if the 03122011 post-tsunami Geo-Eye images on Google Earth / Maps are just not geo-referenced or what, but there is about a 40 foot discrepancy on the old and new aerial images, doubtful the land moved that much, but who knows...

it's amazing how fast they have put these images together so quickly... a word of warning, the after aerial images are pretty stunning, lots of houses and entire towns completely swept away... link is here: [Satellite imagery of Japan Earthquake](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=200910826786863242067.00049e4d08c67e68fe83e&ll=38.272689,140.756836&spn=22.232593,53.569336&t=h&z=5)

Comment: before / after Aerials of Japanese tsunami. 
If you scroll over the photos it gives you the before and after perspective.

http://www.abc.net.au/news/events/japan-quake-2011/beforeafter.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to jump in late as the map is very cool (I'll use it as a resource) but I am not sure it actually answers the question correctly (in a technical manner) despite all the upvotes.

I think the question and answers are confusing the maps, the gps, and even orbital oscillations of the planet in relative space or about an axis.

> The Sendai earthquake a couple days ago has shifted the earth on its axis and moved the island 8 feet.

I'd like to split it into two. First the 8 ft and then then axis part.

1. The island has only moved 8 ft relative to a static non-moving place (which does not really exist) on earth, somewhere. This makes **almost** not one iota of difference to the GPS system. The GPS will report a differing location for say a rock on the island, but the rock relatively moved and not the global positioning system measure. I am hedging a bit as technically the fabric of spacetime would have changed, which would have altered the GPS satellite paths relative to the earth, but it is absolutely immeasurably small (and then some) and massively insignificant and unmeasurable but if mass shifted around our geoid this must happen, but in reality it is a number so small I cannot even imagine it. Although the mass of the earth has stayed the same the mass is now organized slightly differently so it must have altered the fabric of spacetime, which will alter the GPS satellite orbits, but by such a miserably insignificant amount. We are talking a number that is so low I could not write it down.

This is the best I can find for (1) but you have to use you imagination. The earth is actually a more complex shape than this (a geoid) so it is not a perfect sphere and hence the fabric of spacetime is not warped so evenly. If you move mass around the earth then the geoid changes, and hence the fabric of spacetime changes, and hence the satellite "path" is altered.

> Einstein eventually identified the property of spacetime which is responsible for gravity as its curvature. Space and time in Einstein's universe are no longer flat (as implicitly assumed by Newton) but can pushed and pulled, stretched and warped by matter. Gravity feels strongest where spacetime is most curved, and it vanishes where spacetime is flat. This is the core of Einstein's theory of general relativity, which is often summed up in words as follows: "**matter tells spacetime how to curve**, and curved spacetime tells matter how to move".https://einstein.stanford.edu/SPACETIME/spacetime2.html

I am using mass as opposed to matter (incorrectly) but I think you get the drift. It is the bold part that draws me to this conclusion.

[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4otiG4JrKAhUK32MKHRoWDXQQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fearthsky.org%2Fspace%2Fepic-study-confirms-einstein-on-space-time&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc&psig=AFQjCNF3h1X1hMcG0mU5Zhs6_j5YXqvOxw&ust=1452360882839127]

2. Now to deal with the axis part. If you chuck a rock to the other side of your yard I would assume this shifts the earth on its axis but who cares. Certainly not the GPS system. Ditto with the earthquake, as any significant axis shift that GPS could not account for, caused by an earthquake, would have to be so massive we would not be here to take the incorrect GPS measurements. So just as 1, yes technically it did but so does everything and it just does not add up to anything. Even when it is something we need to account for such as a massive earthquake that does not wipe us out the GPS system will correct for this small alteration.

> The Earth's rotation axis does not point exactly along the axis of its angular momentum because it does have a tiny amount of lopsidedness to its distribution of mass.
>   https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1031